# Access is denied

Tags: sharepoint, iframe, wss

I got this code for my sharepoint, but I get a Access is Denied, can anyone help me out here ?

```
<!-- Load and display list - iframe version -->
<!-- Questions and comments: Christophe@PathToSharePoint.com -->

<DIV id="ListPlaceholder"><IMG src="/_layouts/images/GEARS_AN.GIF"></DIV>

<!-- Paste the URL of the source list below: -->
<iframe id="SourceList" style="display:none;" src="xXxXxX" onload="DisplayThisList()"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
function DisplayThisList()
{
var placeholder = document.getElementById("ListPlaceholder");

var displaylist = null;
var sourcelist = document.getElementById("SourceList");

try {
   if(sourcelist.contentWindow)
      // Internet Explorer
      {
        displaylist = sourcelist.contentWindow.document.getElementById("WebPartWPQ1") ;
      }

}
catch(err)
{ 
    alert(err.message);
}

displaylist.removeChild(displaylist.getElementsByTagName("table")[0]);

placeholder.innerHTML = displaylist.innerHTML;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about the error. Formatting the code would help a lot!

Comment: When I get an access is denied error in SharePoint, I find Fiddler invaluable in troubleshooting the error. Given the number of CSS resources being loaded it can quickly help identify the http request causing the error. http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the errror, our sharepoint had multiply names to be access on, so I just changed the URL so it was more dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Is by any chance the iframe loading something from another domain? You can't access the contents of the iframe if it is (for security reasons).

Comment: I will try and look at Fiddler.
and it is just loading a list from another sharepoint site, so it is the same domain.